# Get ZIP file from generated URL

Tags: php, url, zip, request

I have a URL that, when requested, start the download of a .zip file. The URL looks something like this:
http://website.nl/servlets/ogexport?koppeling=WEBSITE&user=**&password=**&og=BOG&kantoor=**

How can I make sure that the zip file that gets generated in that proces get used in my PHP unzip script?

```
$file = 'testing.zip';
$path = pathinfo(realpath($file), PATHINFO_DIRNAME).'/xml';

// unzippen
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$res = $zip->open($file);
if ($res === TRUE) {
    $zip->extractTo($path);
    $zip->close();
            echo 'success';
    // debug("ZIP bestand uitgepakt", 2);
} else {
    // debug("ZIP niet uitgepakt", 2);
    echo 'something went wrong.';
}

$xml_path = $path."/testing.xml";
echo $file.'<br>';
echo $xml_path;
```

Hoping for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using php [curl](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.curl.php) to download the remote file.Here is an [example](http://www.phpriot.com/articles/download-with-curl-and-php)

Comment: How would I get the zip file using that code? It's not a direct link to a zip file, but I think that when visiting the URL it gets generated. Thanks for your answer tough.

Comment: You would use curl to access the URL ,the full output of the url is saved by curl_exec. You save the file or output it to someone else download. Do you an example url?

Comment: That actually worked the first time I tried. I saved the file in the wrong map. Thanks!